# PowerShell using an existing session state to fill in InitialSessionState

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to call\create runspace within a class that derived from PSCmdlet. Since PSCmdlet includes a default session state that contains shared data I want to reuse in the runspace, I am wondering if there is a programmatically way to convert the current sessionState into the runspace's InitialSessionState ?

If there is no such way, I am not really understand why such session state info cannot be shared within different runspace. This looks like running a remote runspace to me. Can anyone explain?

For example,

```
namespace CustomCmdlet.Test
{
    [Cmdlet("Get", "Test1")]
    public class GetTest1 : PSCmdlet
    {
        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        { WriteObject("1"); }
    }

    [Cmdlet("Get", "Test2")]
    public class GetTest2 : PSCmdlet
    {
        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
         // instead of import the module dll using Runspace
         // InitialSessionState.ImportModule(new string[] {"CustomCmdlet.Test.dll"});
         // Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(InitialSessionState)

         // is it any way to import the PSCmdlet.SessionState into the InitialSessionState?
        }
    }
```

We are using PowerShell 4.0, if this is relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Session state definitely can't be shared across runspaces, it holds session specific data like variables.

The InitialSessionState that was used to create a runspace is a property of the runspace.  You can access the current runspace via thread local storage using the Runspace.DefaultRunspace property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace.defaultrunspace(v=vs.85).aspx

That said, you may want to look at RunspacePool - the pool of runspaces will all be created from the same InitialSessionState.  This way you avoid creating more runspaces than necessary, instead just reusing a runspace from the pool.

Comment: To extend from your answer, why is the session states not able to be shared across runspaces? session states has private\public property and can be used by other sessions, and I think runspace is simulating a session?

Comment: Session state is like a scope or stack frame.  It doesn't use any sort of locking, so state shared across runspaces can easily be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is years late, but

```
$maxThreads = 17;
            $iss = [system.management.automation.runspaces.initialsessionstate]::CreateDefault();
            [void]$iss.ImportPSModule($exchangeModule.Path)
            $runspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $maxThreads, $iss, $host)
            $runspacePool.Open() > $null;
            
        #EndRegion Initial sessionstate

        
        #Region Run threads and collect data

            $threads = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
            foreach ($server in $servers)
            {
                if (!($server.ToString().Contains("unreachable")))
                {
                    $powerShell = [powershell]::Create($iss);
                    $powerShell.RunspacePool = $runspacePool;
                    
                    
                    [void]$powerShell.AddScript({       
                        Param ($server)     
                        [pscustomobject]@{

                            server = $server

                        } | Out-Null
                        
                        $global:ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';
                        $returnVal = Get-Queue -Server $server; # | where {$_.MessageCount -gt 1};
                        $customObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject;
                        $customObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ServerName -Value $server;
                        $customObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MessageCountObject -Value $returnVal;
                        #Write-Host "Object return value is is: " $messageCountObject;
                        return $customObject;

                    }) # end of powershell.Add script
                    $powerShell.AddParameter('server', $server) | Out-Null; 
                    $returnVal = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke();
                    $temp = "" | Select PowerShell,returnVal;
                    $temp.PowerShell = $PowerShell;
                    $temp.returnVal = $returnVal;
                    $threads.Add($Temp) | Out-Null;
                }
                else
                {
                    $threads.Add($server) | Out-Null;
                }
            } #foreach server

        #EndRegion Run threads and collect data
```